# Does bebop_autonomy also support the new Parrot Bebop 2?

Tags: ros, bebop-autonomy, ardrone, parrot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm thinking about getting one of these and would like to know this.

Has anyone tried it yet?
Or does anyone know if the SDK changed in comparison to the Bebop 1 and if yes, are there any major changes that would delay support?

If not, how long does it usually take to support something like this?

The package and Github don't mention anything about it yet.

For reference: http://www.parrot.com/products/bebop2/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222435/does-bebop_autonomy-also-support-the-new-parrot-bebop-2?/) by [Caopi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25320/caopi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current version of `bebop_autonomy` (v 0.3) does support both Bebop 1 and 2 (everything works). This version is based on SDK v 3.6. The latest version of the SDK (v 3.7.5) does not support the video stream of Bebop 2 (per its documentation), but I guess this is going to be resolved soon. Whenever Parrot releases a new SDK that supports both Bebop versions (again), I will update `bebop_autonomy` to build against the latest SDK.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0